# can't install specific older version of sklearn to solve the incompatible "SVC attribute error" in pyadio analysis lib

Tags: scikit-learn, pip, installation, version, pyaudioanalysis

This code below is for audio file segmentation.

```
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS
[flagsInd, classesAll, acc, CM] = aS.mtFileClassification("diarizationExample.wav", "svmSM", "svm", True, 'dar.segments.txt')
```

it gives me this warning:

```
C:\Users\Kenzhegaliyev_EK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\Kenzhegaliyev_EK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.svm.classes module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.svm. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.svm is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\Users\Kenzhegaliyev_EK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator SVC from version 0.19.1 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
```

and this error:

```
C:\Users\Kenzhegaliyev_EK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in predict(self, X)
    583         """
    584         check_is_fitted(self)
--> 585         if self.break_ties and self.decision_function_shape == 'ovo':
    586             raise ValueError("break_ties must be False when "
    587                              "decision_function_shape is 'ovo'")

AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'break_ties'
```

apparently, it's a conflict between older & newer versions of SVC in sklearn.

In the warning it tells i should probably use sklearn version = 0.19.1

I tried installing the current and upgrading to **older** sklearn. I can't use shell, it's restricted, so i run all code in jupyter:

```
!pip install sklearn
Installing collected packages: sklearn
Successfully installed sklearn-0.0

import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
'0.22.1'

!pip install --upgrade sklearn==0.19.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn==0.19.1 (from versions: 0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sklearn==0.19.1
```

there is no version 0.19.1 on the official [sklearn website](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/versions.html):

> Web-based documentation is available for versions listed below:
>
> Scikit-learn 0.23.dev0 (dev) documentation (PDF 48.5 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.22.1 (stable) documentation (PDF 48.5 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.21.3 documentation (PDF 46.7 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.20.4 documentation (PDF 45.2 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.19.2 documentation (PDF 42.2 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.18.2 documentation (PDF 46.5 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.17.1 documentation (PDF 46.0 MB)
>
> Scikit-learn 0.16.1 documentation (PDF 56.8 MB)

I tried installing any other old sklearn, what is available:

```
!pip install --upgrade sklearn==0.18.2
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn==0.18.2 (from versions: 0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sklearn==0.18.2

!pip install --upgrade sklearn==0.19.2
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn==0.19.2 (from versions: 0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sklearn==0.19.2
```

How to install the right older sklearn to use the older compatible SVC to make the error go away?

Answer (score 2):

There are very few releases of [sklearn](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/#history). This because [the correct name](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) is `scikit-learn`: https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#history

So run

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.19.1
```

Comment: thx u but why then i can't import scikit-learn? i do "import sklearn"

Comment: i mean if it can't import scikit-learn, why should it be able to upgrade, downgrade the name "scikiet-learn"?